# Maven profiles and application yml file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, yaml

I have a Spring project that I build using the following command

```
mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
```

which worked perfectly by selecting the appropriate properties file based on maven profile

Our current application is now updated to have both application.yml file and properties file

Yml file provides the ability to create properties based on spring profiles

```
#DEV
spring:
    profiles: profile1
environment:
    property1: AAA
    property2: BBB
---
#PROD
spring:
    profiles: profile2
environment:
    property1: CCC
    property2: DDD
---
```

This works fine with spring profiles using `-Dspring.profiles.active=profile1`

Is there a way to read maven profiles (instead of spring profiles) and set properties accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you no longer want to use spring profiles, you only need 1 key of each in the `application.yml`. Taken from your example it could look like so:

```
environment:
  property1: @property1@
  property2: @property2@
```

Then make profiles in your `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <property1>AAA</property1>
            <property2>BBB</property2>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <property1>CCC</property1>
            <property2>DDD</property2>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Used in my application class like so:

```
@Value("${environment.property1}")
private String profileProperty;

@Value("${environment.property2}")
private String settingsProperty;
```

Comment: Could we use it with something like this?
`<profiles>
        ...
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
            ...
        </profile>
    </profiles>`

Comment: I receive an exception when I tried that
---
Exception in thread "main" while scanning for the next token
found character @ '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 2, column 13:
        host: @host-ip@
                ^

 at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:420)
 at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
 at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:586)

Comment: I had those too, when the maven properties wasnt configured properly. Remember to activate your maven profile in your run command. What version of spring are you using? It might not support `@maven.token@` syntax in the yml