# spring.profiles is not working as expected in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

boot config *.yml file.

```
server.port: 2222
spring:
  application:
    name: x-service
  data:
    mongodb:
       host: db.x
       database: x
#       userName: ${db.userName}
#       password: ${db.password}
  rabbitmq:
#    port: ${queue.port}
    host: queue.x
    username: ${queue.userName}
    password: ${queue.password}
    listener:
      max-concurrency: 1
      prefetch: 1
      acknowledge-mode: auto
      auto-startup: true
    dynamic: true

###########DEV##############
spring.profiles: dev
#queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: guest
queue.password: guest
queue.port: 5672

#db.userName: 
#db.password:

falconUrl: http://x.y.com
##########DEFAULT###########
spring.profiles: qa
queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: xuser
queue.password: xpassword
queue.port: 3456

db.userName: xuser
db.password: xpassword

falconUrl: http://x.z.com
```

It gives me org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing MappingNode

```
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    server.port: 2222
    ^
Duplicate key: spring.profiles
 in 'reader', line 47, column 1:
```

error. If I comment properties of one of the profile.It works fine. 
Can anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: afaik that will only work with `spring: profile:` else it will be parsed as a single property. You will have to nest them in order to work..

Answer (score 2):

The error message is actually quite specific and accurate: in the top-level mapping of your YAML file (the one starting with the key-value pair `server.port` and `2222` you have two identical keys (the scalar `spring.profiles`). And duplicate keys are not allowed in YAML, as the are required to be [unique according to the specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping).

The underlying problem is that if you want to change the configuration depending on the environment, you'll have to follow the [documented specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment), which states that:

> A YAML file is actually a sequence of documents separated by --- lines, and each document is parsed separately to a flattened map.
>
> If a YAML document contains a spring.profiles key, then the profiles value (comma-separated list of profiles) is fed into the Spring Environment.acceptsProfiles() and if any of those profiles is active that document is included in the final merge (otherwise not)

Your YAML file is a single implicit YAML document because it lacks the directive indicator `---` that occurs at the beginning of an explicit YAML document. (the YAML directive `...` that indicates end-of-document might not be supported properly supported by snake-yaml, at least it is not mentioned in the examples).

Your code should look like:

```
server.port: 2222
spring:
  application:
    name: x-service
  data:
    mongodb:
       host: db.x
       database: x
#       userName: ${db.userName}
#       password: ${db.password}
  rabbitmq:
#    port: ${queue.port}
    host: queue.x
    username: ${queue.userName}
    password: ${queue.password}
    listener:
      max-concurrency: 1
      prefetch: 1
      acknowledge-mode: auto
      auto-startup: true
    dynamic: true

###########DEV##############
---
spring.profiles: dev
#queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: guest
queue.password: guest
queue.port: 5672

#db.userName: 
#db.password:

falconUrl: http://x.y.com
##########DEFAULT###########
---
spring.profiles: qa
queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: xuser
queue.password: xpassword
queue.port: 3456

db.userName: xuser
db.password: xpassword

falconUrl: http://x.z.com
```

---

The statement in the documentation that "*each document is parsed separately to a flattened map*" is of course only true, if each of the documents has a mapping at the top level. That is what spring-boot expects, but you can as easily have a scalar or sequence at the top level of a document, and such documents are **certainly not** parsed by snake-yaml to a flattened map.

Comment: Anthod,Explaination is wrong. properties can be picked on environment basis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615466/maven-profiles-and-application-yml-file-in-spring. I was missing "---" tag

Comment: I have no idea what you are writing about. '---' is not a tag. In YAML each and every a tag starts with an exclamation mark (`!`)

Comment: Same YML file is working fine after changing as below 
---
###########DEV##############
spring.profiles: dev
#queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: guest
queue.password: guest
falconUrl: http://x.y.com
---
##########DEFAULT###########
spring.profiles: qa
queue.virtual.host: xuser 
queue.userName: xuser
queue.password: xpassword

falconUrl: http://x.z.com

---. Even duplicate keys are supporting and value will be picked as per environment.you can verify same in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html also.

Comment: In YAML `---` is a directive indicator. It ends the directives for a new document and implicitly starts a new document. Of course you can use the same key in top-level mappings of  different YAML documents and the error goes away if you do. But that is not what is wrong with YAML in your post, there you **do have a YAML file with a single one document**. You might as well have made the file empty, then it would not have duplicates keys either.